# How can I loop through each character in a String using JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

How can I loop through each character in a String using JSTL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tricky use of `fn:substring()` would do

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${fn:length(str)}" step="1">
    <c:out value="${fn:substring(str, i, i + 1)}" />     
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Nice - wasn't sure what functions were available

Comment: @Dave you can check all at [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html)

Comment: I meant that I didn't remember off the top of my head, was busy this morning and didn't check the ref docs :-)

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but EL 2.2 allows for instance method calls (more on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7122669/2047962). This means that you could shorten Jigar Joshi's answer by a few characters:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${fn:length(str)}" step="1">
  <c:out value="${str.charAt(i)}" />     
</c:forEach>
```

I only suggest this because it is a little more obvious what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't do that with JSTL's forEach. You need to write your own tag or an EL function. Here is a sample code how you write your custom tags:
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0360__JSP/CustomTagSupport.htm

Comment: Why not? http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html
I see a length function and a substring function here

Comment: fn:substring/fn:length are still EL functions!

Comment: I thought it was bad practice to mix scriptlets with JSTL, while EL should be elegant. Do you mean that EL is not strictly part of JSTL?

Comment: It is true. To use scriptlets in view (jsps) is even worst practice. For that reason you can develop your own custom tags or EL functions. example for custom JSTL tag: <mylib:forEachLetter str="Hello World"><c:out value="${currentLetter}"/></mylib:forEachLetter>