# Regular expression to remove special characters in JSTL tags

Tags: regex, jsp, replace, jstl

I am working on a Spring application and in JSPX page I need to dynamically load some values from properties page and set them as dropdown using  options tag. I need to use same text for options value and for displaying but for options value, I need to remove all special characters.

For example if value is Maternal Uncle, then I need

```
<option value="MaternalUncle">Maternal Uncle</option>
```

What I am getting is

```
<option value="Maternal Uncle">Maternal Uncle</option>
```

There are 2 applications which can use that page and which properties file to load depends on app. If I load values for app 1 then values get displayed properly, Last value in app1 is 'Others' and does not has any special characters. For app 2 it does not trims whitespaces where last value is 'Maternal Uncle'. repOptions in code is ArrayList with values loaded from properties file. Here is my code:

```
<select name="person" id="person">
      <option value="na">Select the relationship</option>
  <c:forEach items="${repOptions}" var="repOption">
       <option value="${fn:replace(repOption, '[^A-Za-z]','')}">${repOption}</option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

First app removes whitespaces as this value is 4th in list of 9. For app2 , this is last value and regex does not works. If I put Maternal Uncle as first property for app2 then this works fine but requirements is to have it last option.

```
 <option value="${fn:replace(repOption, ' ','')}">
```

is working for whitespaces but there can be values like Brother/Sister, so I need to remove / also, hence I am using regex.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The JSTL [`fn:replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/replace.fn.html) does not use a regular expression based replacement. It's just an exact charsequence-by-charsequence replacement, exactly like as [`String#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) does.

JSTL does not offer another EL function for that. You could just homegrow an EL function yourself which delegates to the regex based [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

E.g.

```
package com.example;

public final class Functions {

     private Functions() {
         //
     }

     public static String replaceAll(String string, String pattern, String replacement) {
         return string.replaceAll(pattern, replacement);
     }

}
```

Which you register in a `/WEB-INF/functions.tld` file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <display-name>Custom Functions</display-name>    
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <uri>http://example.com/functions</uri>

    <function>
        <name>replaceAll</name>
        <function-class>com.example.Functions</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</taglib>
```

And finally use as below:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://example.com/functions" prefix="f" %>

...

${f:replaceAll(repOption, '[^A-Za-z]', '')}
```

Or, if you're already on Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 or newer (Tomcat 7 or newer), wherein EL started to support invoking methods with arguments, simply directly invoke `String#replaceAll()` method on the string instance.

```
${repOption.replaceAll('[^A-Za-z]', '')}
```

#### See also:

- [How to call parameterized method from JSP using JSTL/EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121303/how-to-call-parameterized-method-from-jsp-using-jstl/)

Comment: Excellent answer, took care of many headaches I was facing +1