# Replacing Anchor in JSTL

Tags: regex, jsp, servlets, jstl

In my JSP I have receive some data which is coming from database my data is for example something like this :

```
Google is the greatest search engine ever http://www.google.com
```

what I wanna do is so simple: I want to make this link wrap in anchor tag using JSTL something like:

```
Google is the greatest search engine ever <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
```

that's all !
take note that the urls are not constant, I mean I'm not sure what that be exactly & I just mentioned google here for the example.

Comment: Why don't you store `<a href="someLink">` directly in Database.. ? Instead of wrapping it after retrieving from DB..

Comment: @VikasV Because that would be silly. A URL is a URL, and isn't the same as a clickable HTML rendering of the same.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416774/regular-expression-to-remove-special-characters-in-jstl-tags) question to create a `replaceAll` function for JSTL and then use the following pattern to replace the url to html link:

```
        String pattern = "(http:[A-z0-9./~%]+)";

        String str = "Google is the http://www.test.com greatest search engine ever http://www.google.com";

        String replaced = str.replaceAll(pattern, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't wanna use java code in my JSP at all. If I wanna use java code, I had many solution in my hand already.

Comment: ok, but you can create your own taglib to support the replaceAll function and import it to your jsp as suggested in the SO question I referenced.

Comment: so you mean this is not possible to do, using built in JSTL function?

Comment: no, unless you create some 'crazy' logic using the functions below http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html, something like finding the index of the `http` and substring the string, etc...