# JSTL and Regex to replace a email address with a given text

Tags: regex, jstl

I am trying to replace any email address of the form - 'anything@bipsolutions.com' to TRACKER_ADMIN, in a JSP page. I am using JSTL and using a defined function 'fn' which has a replace method. I want to know if I can use regex to do this or of there are any other way-
My code is given below-

```
${fn:replace(logList.action,'*@bipsolutions.com',' Tracker Admin ')}
```

But this is not working properly.

Can any one please provide a help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to remove special characters in JSTL tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416774/regular-expression-to-remove-special-characters-in-jstl-tags)

Comment: hey @BalusC why I got -1 if I have tested and I used this in my script today too???

Comment: so maybe he can try use fn:containsIgnoreCase

Comment: Hi Darka, can you please pass me your code here. Then I can have a look at that.

Comment: @Darka thanks a lot mate, that got sorted with your solution.

Comment: Just for info, I used the following code-  <c:choose>
         <c:when test="${fn:containsIgnoreCase(logList.action, 'admin@bipsolutions.com')}">
              TRACKER_ADMIN
           </c:when>
           <c:otherwise>
           ${fn:replace(logList.action,',',', ')}
        </c:otherwise>
       </c:choose>

Comment: you can put your solution here and then accept it