# Replacing ##abc## with <b>abc</b>

Tags: java, regex, jsp

How can I achieve this?

For example, I need to change `##some text##` to bold (i.e. `<b>some text</b>`). I am using JSTL replace tag and `##(.+?)##` regex to find all those matches.

Any help?

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416774/regular-expression-to-remove-special-characters-in-jstl-tags

Comment: The context here is a bit different than this post. I need the text between ##---## to be preserved.

Comment: Once you have implemented `replaceAll`, you can do like @sguazz said, and replace `##(.+?)##` by `<b>\1</b>`, `\1` references the first matching group (what is between parenthesis).

Comment: @FlorentBayle The matching group can be referenced by `$1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matching group can be references by `$1` (for the first one), `$2` (second one) and so on. Finally, using replaceAll can be used [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10416774/regular-expression-to-remove-special-characters-in-jstl-tags). Replacing of `##(.+?)##` with `<b>$1</b>` will work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing groups (stuff within parenthesis) can be referenced with `\1, \2, \3` and so on - in this case, it'd be \1 because it's the first one that appears in the regex.

So, try replacing `##(.+?)##` with `<b>\1</b>`.

Comment: I tried to do it and couldn't be referenced. Are you sure you are giving answers without assumption?

Comment: Actually, no, I'm not sure. I'm not familiar with JSTL - this is simply how I would've done it in any of the environments I'm used to (different languages maybe, or even manual find/replace in many editors). If JSTL is not that flexible (which I find strange - are you following the suggestions in the link in the original post?), maybe we need some sort of workaround. What's the context of those strings? Do they appear within other text? Are they surrounded by other stuff that would help you distinguish the "opening" ## from the "closing" one, so that you could just replace twice?