# Replace newline and double quotes characters in a string using JSP and JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

We can remove break line from a string using,

```
${fn:replace(data, '\n', ' ')}
```

but how to replace both newline and double quotes from a string using a single replace function.Please help.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible to do what you are trying to do. Not with one `replace()` since it doesn't accept regular expressions.

Though you could chain the replace() calls like this:

```
${fn:replace(fn:replace(data, '"',' '), '\n', ' ')}
```

as [@alfreema](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2957186/alfreema) suggested in the comments below.

Or you can implement your own replace function as mentioned in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10417446/486332

Comment: Thanks.But I want to do it using JSTL.

Comment: This is shameful, I didn't notice the tags adn just thought it was just another JS question and second though was "looks like some sort of weird JQUERY, who knows what are they up to these days."  
Either way, it looks like there is no regex replace in JSTL, you will have to roll out your own http://stackoverflow.com/a/10417446/486332

Comment: Not a single replace function, but you can chain them like:  ${fn:replace(fn:replace(data, '"',' '), '\n', ' ')}