# How to use fn:replace(string,pattern,replace) with regex?

Tags: regex, jsp, replace, find

I would like to use replace to find `'[' and ']'` in a string and replace it with `blank spaces`.

I have tried the following :

```
${fn:replace('[aus,zar]','(\[|\])','')}
```

but my system throw an Exception.

Comment: The [`fn:replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/replace.fn.html) does not use a regular expression based replacement. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10417446/3832970). Use `.replaceAll("[\\]\\[]+", "")`.

Comment: You may try `${fn:replace(fn:replace('[aus,zar]', ']', ''), '[', '')}` if you only need to handle these 2 `[` and `]` chars.

Comment: That does not seem to work as well its throwing an Exception again.

Comment: Then go ahead and implement a custom EL function that delegates to the regex-based `String#replaceAll()` as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10417446/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

See, in `regular expressions (regex)`, **'['** and **']'** have different meanings as character classes. If you want to match them then you need to escape them by adding a backslash **''**.
Also, **'|'** character is used to specify `alternatives` in regex, so it needs to be escaped as well.
Refer the code given below

```
${fn:replace('[aus,zar]', '\\[|\\]', '')}
```

This may solve the issue, If not, kindly comment down the issue.