# JSTL to access superclass property

Tags: java, jstl, superclass

Good morning!

Here's the deal guys, I have a class that my view is passed that I want to access via JSTL. My question is, does anyone know of a way to access superclass properties of that class?

e.g.

> < p >${myClass.greeting}< /p >

Assuming a hypothetical,

```
class mySuperClass{
    private String greeting = "I love stack overflow";

    public String getGreeting(){
        return greeting;
    }
}//end mySuperClass

class myClass extends mySuperClass{
    private String notImportant = "I like applesauce";

    public String getNotImportant(){
        return notImportant;
    }//end notImportant

}//end myClass
```

Comment: what you did, will work. nothing extra have to be done.

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121303/how-to-call-parameterized-method-from-jsp-using-jstl

Comment: Thanks Sajan, I just posted an answer--"Problem Exists Between Keyboard and Chair"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow I'm a dope . . .

So I was actually trying to get a property like,

> < p >${myClass.getGreeting}< /p >

i.e., calling the full accessor name as opposed to,

> < p >${myClass.greeting}< /p >

Sorry, I've been staring this page in the eye for a little too long. Tip of the hat to Sajan Chandran for making my double-take.