# jsp scriplet use function with bean value

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl

I am using display:table with display:column along with bean:write to print out some values from my request.

```
<bean:write name="DisplayBookForm" property="bookType" />
```

I have an import like

```
<%@page import="org.model.MyConstants"%>
```

In there I have a simple function

```
public static String getBookTypeName(int id){
     //lots of if's based on id 
     String bookTypeName = "Fantasy";
     return bookTypeName;
}
```

Is there anyway I could pass in my DisplayBookForm bookType property value into this function and then display its String return? Something like:

```
<c:out value="<%=MyConstants.getBookTypeName(${DisplayBookForm.bookType}) %>" />
<%=MyConstants.getBookTypeName(${DisplayBookForm.bookType})%>
```

Which seem to not work, perhaps set the bean using c:set and then use it in the <% tags?

Comment: Yes you can first set var using C:set and then use that variable in c:out .

Comment: To call parameterised method, this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121303/how-to-call-parameterized-method-from-jsp-using-jstl.