# Method inside loop in jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying to invoke a method inside a loop in jstl but when I type in period after SQLHelper I am not getting the method name.

```
<%@page import="com.servlet.session.SQLHelper"%>
<c:set var="pc" value="${0}" />  
<c:forEach var="report" items="${report2}" varStatus="iter">
<tr id="test">
<c:set var="pc" value="<% pc + SQLHelper.GetCount(${report.id}, ${d1},   ${d2}); %>" />

</c:forEach>
```

what is the correct way to call the method?

Comment: Do you mean that code completion is not working in your editor?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121303/how-to-call-parameterized-method-from-jsp-using-jstl) approach.

Also please note that you can only call methods with arguments in EL if you're  running a Servlet 3.0 compatible container (e.g. Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc) with a web.xml declaring Servlet 3.0.