# Pass variable to spring getter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

**SCENARIO**
I have a group of entities in my app that have independent translation depending of some user choices, different of labels, errors and descriptions that are localized in `properties` files.

All this entities `extends I18N` a super class with methods, the important now is this:

```
public String getName(int language) {
    switch(language) {
    // returns the localized name of the object.
}
```

In the view, there is a dropbox with some items that change the name depending of another language dropbox in same form (remember, it does not change the  language of the application!!). But as long as I can call other getters without parameters, if I try to call `getName(language)` like `item.name(1)`:

**TRIES**
I tried in regular way:

```
<form:options items="${someI18NClass.items}" itemLabel="name(1)" itemValue="id"/>
```

But is showing a [`org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/NotReadablePropertyException.html):

> Bean property 'name(1)' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

And with a bit of workaround:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${someI18NClass.items}">
    <form:option value="${item.id}"><c:out value="${item.name(1)}"/></form:option>
    //                    ↑ OK!                               ↑ PNFE here!
</c:forEach>
```

But is showing a [`javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/el/PropertyNotFoundException.html):

> Property 'name' not found in class com.test.SomeI18NClass.

I also tried [Constructor Injection](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators) but as long as I'm not creating this dropbox items I cannot find the way to use it...

**PROBLEM**
I know this getter breaks the POJO rules accepting the argument, so:

**QUESTION**

- There is some way to pass some parameters to a method in Spring?
- There is any workaround I can make to `I18N` class to have a getter without accepting arguments BUT returning the correct result

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121303/how-to-call-parameterized-method-from-jsp-using-jstl

Comment: @Amit.rk3 with a bit of workaround it did the trick for me.... please, post it as answer so I can mark question as solved ;)

Comment: Done :) . So what was the final code that worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are on EL 2.2 , you can do `${item.getName(1)}`

Comment: second workaround with `<for:each>` is the one that worked calling method direct: `<form:option value="${item.id}"><c:out value="${item.getName(mainFormClass.idiom.id)}"/></form:option>`

Comment: @JordiCastilla : okies.. that's great !