# Injecting JSP EL and/or JSTL tags from Java code

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have Java classes which are used on a JSP page. `getAttr()` returns a string with an arbitrary number of HTML anchor elements leading to URLs local to my web application:

```
public class C {
    public String getAttr() {
        return "foo <a href = \"/index.html\">bar</a> baz";
    }
}
```

and

```
<c:set var = "c" value = "..."/>
${c.attr}
```

As long as the default context (`/`) is used, everything's fine. Non-default contexts can be accounted for by using smth like `<a href = "<c:url value = "..."/>">...</a>`, but this is JSP-specific. JSTL/EL injection from Java code like `return "<a href = \"<c:url value = \"...\"/>\">...</a>";` doesn't (and shouldn't) work.

How can I support non-default context without exposing the internals of my Java classes? Manual hyperlink creation outside of JSP scope is at least ugly, but I've run out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get HttpServletRequest in your Class c:

```
public class C {

    private HttpServletRequest request;
    //initialize request in a constructor

    public String getAttr() {
        return "foo <a href = \""+request.getContextPath()+"/index.html\">bar</a> baz";
    }
}
```

Comment: I want my class to be JSP-agnostic, so I worked around the problem by passing `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` as the only `String` parameter to `getAttr(...)`. From the JSP perspective, this looks like `${c.getAttr(pageContext.request.contextPath)}`. It hasn't occurred to me in the first place, that JSP EL 2.2+ (Tomcat 6+) allows [invoking arbitrary instance methods with arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7122669/1343979). Then I just re-implemented `org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.UrlSupport#resolveUrl()` in my Java code.